# span element in an image alt attribute

Tags: html

Does anyone know how to add `<span>` to an image alt attribute?
I have tried by doing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="example.jpeg" alt="this is what the colors looked like : <span style="color: red">Example</span>">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid breaking the continuity of the `alt` attribute by using a single quote instead of a double quote to delimit the `span`'s `style` attribute.

```
<img src="example.jpeg" alt="this is what the colors looked like : <span style='color: red'>Example</span>">
```

But that doesn't mean a browser will render the alt text as anything other than plain text. Doing that would pretty much defeat the point of the attribute in the first place.

The attribute is intended to be used by the likes of screen readers which will read aloud the page content for the visually impaired etc. and plain text browsers, neither of which care about the colour of the text only the text itself.

To conform to standards the alt text in this instance should probably just be something like "Example text coloured in red".

Comment: @AGMPenguin That is what I am saying - perhaps my wording was not direct enough. You can fix the syntax as I suggested but the effect you are trying to achieve is not possible. Browsers render the `alt` attribute as text, always. The `span` (or any other) tag will not be processed. This is by design.